# Flask receiving empty POST form

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Can't understand, why this code doesn't work, i was trying to understand, but i'm only learning Flask&Py, help me please:

Flask:

```
@freepylib.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signup_user():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username, useremail, userpasswd=request.form['name'], request.form['email'], request.form['password']
        reg = Users(uname=username, useremail=useremail, upasswrd=userpasswd)
        try:
            mydb.session.add(reg)
            mydb.session.commit()
            token = reg.get_token()
            return {'access_token': token}
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" name="reg" id="reg">
  <input type ="text" class ="fadeIn second" name ="name" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" class="fadeIn second" name="email"  placeholder="email">
  <input type="text" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" name="subm" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Error:

```
(pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048, "Column 'uname' cannot be null") [SQL: INSERT INTO `PFL_USERS` (uname, email, upasswrd) VALUES (%(uname)s, %(email)s, %(upasswrd)s)] [parameters: {'uname': None, 'email': None, 'upasswrd': None}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
```

Comment: Could you try using the Network tab in Chrome DevTools to confirm that the POST request actually includes the form data as you expect?

Comment: @ChrisSears, yep, i've found them in Payload, and status code is 200

Comment: Then the next thing I'd check is to log the request.form values to see if the form data is getting that far.

Comment: @ChrisSears, done, added write to file before  reg = Users(uname=username, useremail=useremail, upasswrd=userpasswd), all parameters was written to file, what i can do next?

Comment: def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.uname = kwargs.get('name')
        self.email = kwargs.get('email')
        self.upasswrd = kwargs.get('password')

    def get_token(self, expire_time=1):
        expire_delta = timedelta(expire_time)
        token = create_access_token(
            identity=self.uid, expires_delta=expire_delta)
        return token

Comment: def get_token(self, expire_time=1):
        expire_delta = timedelta(expire_time)
        token = create_access_token(
            identity=self.uid, expires_delta=expire_delta)
        return token

    @classmethod
    def auth(cls, email, password):
        user = cls.query.filter(cls.email == email).one()
        if not check_password(Users.upasswrd,password):
            raise Exception('No user with this password')
        return user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your Users class, in the `__init__`. The kwargs need to match up with how you're calling the constructor from your app code.

For example, changing it to this should help:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
    self.uname = kwargs.get('uname')
    self.email = kwargs.get('useremail') 
    self.upasswrd = kwargs.get('upasswrd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to @ChrisSears, you make my day

Problem was in class, which i forget to add(i'm really sorry)

So, i'll describe:

```
reg = Users(uname=username, email=useremail, upasswrd=hash_password(userpasswd))
```

Using this, i've transfer data into Class Users:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.uname = kwargs.get('name')
    self.email = kwargs.get('email')
    self.upasswrd = kwargs.get('password')
```

As we can see, name of variables is not correct, so there is the problem, it should be like this:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.uname = kwargs.get('uname')
    self.email = kwargs.get('email')
    self.upasswrd = kwargs.get('upasswrd')
```